# Is there a way to burn video on dvd and set "expire time" of it to be watched?

Tags: video, programming

I'd like to ask if there is an possibility to make a dvd-disk that would read from dvd-player clock and compare it to "expiry" data on dvd disk itself.

If the date is after "expiry" date then dvd wouldn't show its content.

I'm aware that someone could just change dvd-player time, but I would like to do it another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not only no way to do this with DVD, but there is no way to do this in any platform where you release the content.  If they can see it, they can record it.  Any measures that you can put in their way are simply DRM and have the analog hole.

Using streaming media is probably the closest you could come, but that still doesn't guarantee that it won't be copied.  The only sure option is to have a guard play it for someone and have them ensure that they do not have a means of recording going.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't - DVD authoring does not include 'expiry' option.

Answer (score 0):

One more better solution is to trim the part you don't want to show. And there is really no such expiry function is most of dvd creators as i know.